# Saving multiple Images at once to the database with a FileUpload Control

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, file-upload

I am working on a company Blog site, and when a user is making a post, they can add an image from their computer to the post. I used a FileUpload control to do this, and it works great. However, I am trying to change the functionality to allow the user to select and upload multiple images in one post, and I am running into some issues. I have set the 'allow multiple' property to 'true', however once multiple images are selected into the control (Image URLs get separated by a comma) and the post button is clicked, only one of the images is inserted into the database, but it is inserted as many times as images there are, and only that one image is displayed on the blog post. So if I try to add three different images, it inserts three instances of the first image into the database. The code corresponding to the the FileUpload in my onClick function is below:

```
  if (imageUpload.HasFile == true)
                {

                    SqlCommand maxMessId = new SqlCommand("SELECT Max(MessageID) FROM BlogMessages", conn);
                    lastMessageID = Convert.ToInt32(maxMessId.ExecuteScalar());

                    foreach (var uploadedFile in imageUpload.PostedFiles)
                    {



                        SqlCommand cmdInsertImage = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO BlogImages(Image, MessageID) VALUES (@Image, @MessageID)", conn);

                        cmdInsertImage.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Image", SqlDbType.Image).Value = imageUpload.FileBytes;
                        cmdInsertImage.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MessageID", lastMessageID);


                        cmdInsertImage.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    }
                }
```

I am thinking the issue could be with:

```
cmdInsertImage.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Image", SqlDbType.Image).Value = imageUpload.FileBytes;
```

If that is getting the file bytes for only one image.. I am not sure how to get the filebytes for both files. The image column in my BlogImages table is of the type Image.

Any suggestions are much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that you're working on the right way ?????PostesFiles are the list of file and each one has it own properties you need to read from there.....nothing else

Here a simples examples

```
 For Each xx In fp.PostedFiles
        xx.InputStream
        xx.ContentLength
        xx.FileName


    Next
```

Where those properties upon expose Inputstrem a stream of the image,ContenteLenght it lenght, Filename the filename of the images.So when you pass the imageupload.FileBytes is not the correct way to achive your goal.You have to read the stream and return a bytearray to save the data withing your sql server.Nothing else i hope it could help you to solve your issue.

**UPDATE***

Assume that you're into the foreach loop for each single file you have to setup its own bytearray

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
file.PostedFile.InputStream.CopyTo(ms);
var byts = ms.ToArray();
ms.Dispose();
```

then

change your insert statement like this

```
    cmdInsertImage.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Image", SqlDbType.Image).Value = byts;
```

not tested but it should solve the issue.

**UPDATE 2**

```
if (test.HasFiles) {

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();


    foreach (void el_loopVariable in test.PostedFiles) {
        el = el_loopVariable;
        sb.AppendLine("FILENAME:<B>" + el.FileName.ToString + "</B><BR/>");
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        el.InputStream.CopyTo(ms);
        byte[] byts = ms.ToArray;
        ms.Dispose();


        sb.AppendLine(string.Join(";", byts));
        sb.AppendLine("<br/<br/>");
        byts = null;
    }


    LitResponse.Text = sb.ToString;





}
```

Comment: I think that I understand what you are saying, but the thing is that the code as I have it is indeed saving an image to my database properly (in regards to one image) but the issue is when I have multiple images selected in the FileUpload, only the first image is saved to the database, and it is saved to the database as many times as there are images selected. It's as if all of the unique selected images are replaced with duplicates of the first image and then inserted into the database.

Comment: coz you're call only imagefileupload.filebytes which expose a byte array of the file.So i assuming(not tested) that you have to iterate to build the bytearray and save each single images. let me update my code

Comment: I like where your going with this! However, when you say file.PostedFile.InputStream.CopyTo(ms) do you mean imageUpload.PostedFile? (imageUpload is the name of my FileUpload) Because I can't use the var in the for each for .PostedFile. I assumed this is what was meant and ran the code, I tried it as you have it and I also tried moving ms.Dispose to the very end of the foreach loop, but both ways it inserts the one image into the database, and the other two images as null. (0x)

Comment: yes i took a simple example from my apps and reported here file.postedfile is equal to imageupload.postedfile :) you're right

Comment: it's a weird behavior let me check at my end

Comment: take a look to the update it work fine at my end i see all files with their bytes.PS Excuse me for my english but i'm italian :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57053/discussion-between-leostotch-and-makemoney2010).

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that in your for each loop, you're stepping through the posted files, but you're still just using ImageUpload.FileBytes each time, which I expect would be returning the same thing each time.

I'm not super familiar with the file upload control, but maybe you can use the ContentLength property of your uploaded file object to index into the byte array returned by ImageUpload.FileBytes (assuming that array contains each of the multiple files).

Comment: I edited my question a bit as I noticed something was not quite as I described. It seems as though imageUpload.FileBytes is returning only one of the files multiple times, so I am not sure how using the ContentLength property would help

Answer (score 0):

protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

```
     string strImageName = txtImage.Text.ToString();      //to store image into sql database.



                if (FileUpload1.PostedFile != null &&
                FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName != "")
                  {
                       byte[] imageSize = new byte[FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength];
                       HttpPostedFile uploadedImage = FileUpload1.PostedFile;
                       uploadedImage.InputStream.Read(imageSize, 0, (int)FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength);


                // Create SQL Command 

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Pictures(ID,ImageName,Image)" +
                           " VALUES (@ID,@ImageName,@Image)";
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.Connection = conn;

                //retrieve latest ID from tables which was stored in session.
                int ID = Convert.ToInt32(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["ID"].ToString());

                SqlParameter ID = new SqlParameter
                            ("@ID", SqlDbType.Int, 5);
                ID.Value = (Int32)ID;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(ID);

                SqlParameter ImageName = new SqlParameter
                            ("@ImageName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
                ImageName.Value = strImageName.ToString();
                cmd.Parameters.Add(ImageName);

                SqlParameter UploadedImage = new SqlParameter("@Image", SqlDbType.Image, imageSize.Length);
                UploadedImage.Value = imageSize;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(UploadedImage);
                conn.Open();
                int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                conn.Close();
                if (result > 0)
                    lblMessage.Text = "File Uploaded";
                lblSuccess.Text = "Successful !";


  }}
```

Comment: Can you add a brief summary of what pieces of your code does that helps solve the problem, in addition to the in-line comments?  Thanks!